# Accessing values in array of pointer inside of a struct

Tags: c

I am trying to access the values of struct members inside an array of struct pointers inside of a struct.  So I have a struct Room that contains an array of pointers to other Rooms called outboundConnection[].  I keep getting the error

> error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
>   printf("Connection %i: %s", i, x.outboundConnections[i].name);

My struct is set up like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name; //Name of the room
    char type; //Type of room
    int numOutboundConnections; //Number of rooms connected
    int isSelected;; // 0 means not selected, 1 means selected 
    struct Room *outboundConnections[6]; //Pointers to rooms connected
} Room;
// Room constructor used for filling roomBank
Room room_init(char* name, int s, int c)
{
    Room temp;
    temp.name = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp.name, name);
    temp.isSelected = s;
    temp.numOutboundConnections = c;
    return temp;
}
```

I am adding connections  to the outboundConnections array using this function:

```
void ConnectRoom(Room *x, Room *y)
{
    (*x).outboundConnections[(*x).numOutboundConnections] = malloc(sizeof(Room));
    (*x).outboundConnections[(*x).numOutboundConnections] = y;
    (*x).numOutboundConnections++;
    (*y).outboundConnections[(*y).numOutboundConnections] = malloc(sizeof(Room));
    (*y).outboundConnections[(*y).numOutboundConnections] = x;
    (*y).numOutboundConnections++;
}
```

I am having issues with getting the name struct member in the outboundConnections array.

```
printf("Connection %i: %s", i, x.outboundConnections[i].name);
```

I have tried using ->name and (*x.outboundConnections[i]).name. I am wondering if I am even correctly assigning Rooms to the outboundConnections array or if my issue is how I am trying to access the member variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outboundConnections` is an array of pointers, so you have to dereference the pointer to get to the `name` member.

```
printf("Connection %i: %s", i, x->outboundConnections[i]->name);
```

In all cases where you write `(*x).something` you can simplify that to `x->something`.

Another problem is in the declaration of the structure itself. You have:

```
struct Room *outboundConnections[6];
```

but you've never declared `struct Room`. You declared an anonymous structure and then gave it a `typedef Room`. You need to change the declaration to:

```
typedef struct Room
{
    char* name; //Name of the room
    char type; //Type of room
    int numOutboundConnections; //Number of rooms connected
    int isSelected;; // 0 means not selected, 1 means selected 
    struct Room *outboundConnections[6]; //Pointers to rooms connected
} Room;
```

Comment: I tried this an got another error of error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Room’)

Comment: I don't understand that. `x` is `Room*`, not `Room`.

Comment: You didn't do `temp->`, did you? `temp` is a structure, not a pointer.

Comment: You need to go back to your textbook or tutorial and review the sections on structures and pointers, so you know when to use `.` or `->`.

Comment: I did not use `temp` to try to access.  And I am reviewing those sections/lectures, I am just having issues because I have not done something like this in the C language.

Comment: It was in a function I wrote just to test accessing the `outboundConnection` array, but I just moved it into `main` and used: `printf("Connection 1: %s", gameRooms[1]->outboundConnections[1]->name);`
I am still getting the same error here. `gameRooms` is a global array of Room structs.

Comment: What is the declaration of `gameRooms`? Is it `Room *gameRooms[]` or `Room GameRooms[]`?

Comment: If it's an array of `Room` structs then it should be `gameRooms[1].outboundConnections[1]->name`.

Comment: You use `.` with structs, you use `->` with pointers to structs.

Comment: The declaration is `Room gameRooms[7]` which makes sense that I would use `gameRooms[1].outboundConnections[1]->name` instead of `->` notation. But now I am getting `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` on the `->name`

Comment: You don't have `struct Room` declared anywhere.

Comment: Recommend not `typedef`ing `stuct`s; it's confusing; (see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs).

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I did not know I also needed to place the name of the struct after the `typedef struct`.  So now I just need to use `.` notation for accessing the `outboundConnections` array and `->` notation for accessing the member variables of the Rooms in the array.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`outboundConnections` is an array of pointers, so `outboundConnections[i]` is a `Room *`. Also, `x` is a pointer as well.  You should use `->` (as opposed to `.`) to access its members:

```
x->outboundConnections[i]->name
```

Comment: I tried this an got another error of
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Room’)

Comment: where does this `printf` appear.  In that context, what is `x`?

Comment: It in in a function where I was trying to print out the name member variable of the Room structs in outboundConnections. Here is the function:
`void testConnections(Room x)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<6; i++)
 {
  printf("Connection %i: %s", i, x->outboundConnections[i]->name);
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

First off, replace the `(*x).` notation with `x->` as others have pointed out.

But more importantly, when you do this:

```
(*x).outboundConnections[(*x).numOutboundConnections] = malloc(sizeof(Room));
(*x).outboundConnections[(*x).numOutboundConnections] = y;
```

You just leaked `sizeof(Room)` bytes. The `malloc` call is unnecessary if you're storing pointers to `Room`. You would only need it if you were storing a *copy* of `Room`. So your code should look like this if you're storing pointers:

```
x->outboundConnections[x->numOutboundConnections] = y;
```

Or this if you're storing a copy of `Room`:

```
x->outboundConnections[x->numOutboundConnections] = malloc(sizeof(Room));
*x->outboundConnections[x->numOutboundConnections] = *y;
```